# Best way to represent comparative information in paragraph form?

Tags: comparatives, repetition

Let's say normally I have a table, and the left hand column has a requirement in it, and the right hand column has how the requirement is fulfilled.  But because of a lack of support for tables, I need to represent this in the briefest manner possible for many, many items, without committing the literary sin of the text becoming boring, because I am repetitious in everything but the nouns.  How do I do this?

Comment: How man is "many, many items"?

Comment: @JLG anywhere from 10 to 30 items.

Comment: Why the down vote? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: It wasn't my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example, write:

> *Requirement A is fulfilled by taking Class A; Requirement B by Class B; Requirement C by Class C; Requirement D by Class D* ... and so on.

The "is fulfilled by taking" is understood in the clauses following the initial one. I can't say that it will be riveting reading, but it should be clear.